# Mock an object with a private constructor of a class which I can't modify

Tags: c#, testing, mocking

I'm facing the following issue:
I'm using a really badly designed API (and no there is no alternative, using a different one is not an option) and I would like to write a few tests but they rely on an instance of a class, let's call it `A`, that have a private constructor.

I need to mock that `A`, I don't care about original behavior at all, the problem is that I can't change the original class.

What are my alternatives? Coming from ruby which is not statically typed, I think there is no way to do this, so I have no idea how to come up with this problem.

It's not the first time that I have a private constructor for a class that it's not a singleton (probably it's not private, it's internal, but in any case I don't have access to it)

Comment: You can't change `A`, you say, but can you change the code that uses `A`? If so, you can replace your references in that to `A` with an adapter (an intermediary with an exposed interface) that you can subsequently mock.

Comment: This is a valid suggestion. However there is one bad thing about this: A has something like 80 methods, I suppose I can mock a few, but it will be really boring mock all 80 methods, sigh. I guess I can't do anything about it: badly designed API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem working with legacy code, leading to the classic chicken and egg problem: you can't change the code unless you've got tests, but you can't write tests without changing the code.

I found my way out using [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh549175), which can mock almost everything, including private constructors. Unfortunately, it's only included with the Premium and Ultimate editions of Visual Studio (not Professional). If you don't have that, all is not lost -- [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/), the research project that eventually spawned Fakes, is still available as a free download and works mostly the same.

I should point out that, once you are able to write tests and change code reliably using Fakes/Moles, the best thing to do is to use this new power to make the API more testable, if only because Fakes/Moles are fairly slow and will add overhead to the testing process.

Comment: Thanks man, this is something really great. I'm still thinking if in any case the best approach is a big wrapper around `A`, probably yes, but starting with Moles and Microsoft Fakes seems like a great idea.